# Compare education_history using FQL

Tags: facebook-fql

Am trying to list out the friends according to the COLLEGE/SCHOOL they attended.
Suppose the person is in college XYZ

Am trying this:

```
SELECT uid, name, education_history.name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 from friend where uid1=me())  AND strpos(education_history.name,'XYZ') >0
```

But sadly,it ain't returning any data.
Can you correct me.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't look like you can get this. You can query inside some arrays with FQL. Some you can't. `education_history` and `education` both look like arrays you can't query inside.

Comment: Well can i save the data generated through the fql to some variables say db_name for name? If yes,how?

Comment: Sure. You can always request more data than you need from FQL and filter it in your script. The how part of your question is going to depend a lot on the programming language you're using.

Comment: Am using php. Am quite new to facebook develpoment.Can you help me out? :)

Comment: Use the [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php) and then you'll have the result from Facebook in an array. Loop through it like this: `foreach ($result as $item){ if (0 < strpos($item['education_history']['name'], 'XYZ')) { $people_from_XYZ[] = $item; } }` and `$people_from_XYZ` will have the records you want.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments you cannot query the sub-field of `education_history` you need to post process the data.